# Cloud-init installing packages on Debian with contrib sources

Tags: debian, zfs, cloud-init

I need to install some zfs packages on Debian instances using cloud-init. One of the packages needs the contrib sources. I can get it to update the sources list, but the packages fail to install.  If I remove the contrib source lists, some packages install, just not the ones that need contrib. Kind of a catch 22.  Has anyone had success installing zfs and all prerequisites using cloud-init?

Here is what I am using, when I add `package_update` or `preserve_sources_list: true` it fails to update the sources.list file. I can't win. lol  Thanks!

```
#cloud-config
locale: en_US.UTF-8
timezone: America/New_York
apt:
  sources_list: | # needed for spl package
    deb $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye main contrib
    deb-src $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye main contrib
    deb $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye-updates main contrib
    deb-src $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye-updates main contrib
    deb $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye-security main contrib
    deb-src $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye-security main contrib
packages:
  - linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64
  - linux-image-amd64
  - spl
  - kmod
  - snapd
  - nfs-common
  - htop
  - nano
  - build-essential
  - zfsutils-linux
  - zfs-dkms
  - zfs-zed
runcmd:
  - mkdir /mnt/v-nas
  - mkdir /mnt/home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source lines look wrong. On debian bullsye, `$RELEASE` will be replaced with `bullseye`.

Therefore this:

```
deb $MIRROR $RELEASE bullseye main contrib
```

Should get rendered into your apt list config as:

```
deb http://some.site.com/ bullseye bullseye main contrib
```

Is that really supposed to have two `bullseye` entries?